# Is there a way to make the NetBeans output pane not go transparent?

Tags: netbeans, preferences

Is there a way to make the NetBeans output pane not go transparent?  I put the output pane on a separate monitor, but when it loses focus it goes transparent, and I cannot read it.  I've looked for a configuration setting, but I haven't had any luck finding it.  Is there a setting for this?  How can I keep it from becoming transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Netbeans 7.2, Try clicking `Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous Tab -> Windows sub-tab`, then unchecking the 
`Transparent floating windows` box.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans 8.0:

- `Options`
- `Appearance`
- `Windows`
- Untick `Transparent floating windows`